# How to invalidate session with Controller using symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

My application is being migrated from symfony 3 to symfony 4, 
I dont know whether this is a symfony 4 bug or not.

Im using a rest api that uses a controller which creates and removes a session.

when I create a session and set a variable.

```
$session = new Session(); // or $this->get("session") 
$session->start();
$session->set("key", "value");
```

and try to invalidate the sesssion.
(Ive tried all of these)

```
$session = new Session();
$session->invalidate(1);
$session->clear();

$this->get("session")->invalidate(1);

$request->getSession()->invalidate(1);
```

the value can still get accessed with the get method.
e.g with

```
$request->getSession()->get("key");
```

Also the services to set the token to null and not available anymore.

Comment: the only thing I can see that might be an issue is passing a parameter to `invalidate`.  If you [check the docs](https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#method_invalidate) the parameter is lifetime.  Is this what you meant to do?

Comment: Ive set invalidate to 1 second, thinking the parameter was now required but it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 1):

First get the currently existing session

```
$session = $this->get('session');
```

To set a variable:

```
$session->set('key', 'value');
```

To clear all variables:

```
$session->clear();
```

To invalidate the session

```
$session->invalidate();
```

When I then do

```
var_dump($request->getSession()->get("key"));
```

it returns null

**I guess the problem is that you set $session twice**

```
$session = new Session();

$session->set('key', 'value');

$session = new Session();

$session->invalidate(1);

var_dump($request->getSession()->get("key"));
```

This returns string 'value' while

```
$session = new Session();

$session->set('key', 'value');

$session->invalidate(1);

var_dump($request->getSession()->get("key"));
```

returns null